# store a reference to a variable in SQL table

Tags: php, sql

How would it be possible to store a reference to a variable in SQL table? I have this code:

```
$id = 10;
$variable_value = 'real value';
$connect_db=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'this', 'that', 'a_table');
$result = $connect_db->query("SELECT * FROM the_table where id = '$id'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$the_function = $row['trigger']; // this row has a value '$variable_value' (w.o quotes)
echo '$the_function:'.$the_function.'<br>'; // echoes '$variable_value'
```

Is possible to have it echo 'real value' instead?

Comment: Do you want to save the **$variable_value** into the database?

Comment: No, I want to save the reference to $variable_value into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable variables to double-evaluate what you have in your database value:

```
$the_function = "variable_value";

echo $$the_function;
```

outputs

```
real value
```

Note that you don't need to prepend your database value with a `$`, you'll only complicate matters.

Also the fact that you call it "the_function" makes me think you want to use this to call a function whose name is the variable... well you can also do this!

```
function variable_value() {
   echo "real value"; 
}
$the_function();
```

Here are both methods in action:

https://eval.in/92869

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $the_function = $row['trigger']; // this row has a value '$variable_value' (w.o quotes)
 $the_function = ltrim($the_function,'$');
 echo '$the_function:'.${$the_function}.'<br>';
```

It's called a variable variable name. [Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

For this to work the `$` has to be removed. So I left-trim it out from your `$the_function` and use `${$<variable_name>}` to reference it as a variable of its value.